# How to convert python dictionary to dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dictionary in python

```
 {'CARDIAC SURGERY':      IPD_Date  forecasted  net_bill_amount        flag
 0  2012-08-31  936400.306       467600.000       Train
 1  2012-09-30 1812637.364      2915615.000       Train
 2  2012-10-31 2829177.535      4369266.700       Train
 3  2012-11-30 2849109.782      4152424.500       Train,
  'OPTHALMIC':      IPD_Date  forecasted  net_bill_amount        flag
 0  2012-08-31   81881.051        75734.000       Train
 1  2012-09-30  238591.765       202252.000       Train
 2  2012-10-31  324813.299       345450.000       Train
 3  2012-11-30  310018.236       277028.000       Train}
```

How do I convert this dictionary in dataframe in pandas

I have tried following

```
df= pd.DataFrame(dict_df.items())
```

But, this is not working as expected. My desired dataframe is following

```
 Dept                   IPD_Date     forecasted   net_bill_amount     flag     
 CARDIAC SURGERY        2012-08-31  936400.306       467600.000       Train
 CARDIAC SURGERY        2012-09-30 1812637.364      2915615.000       Train
 CARDIAC SURGERY        2012-10-31 2829177.535      4369266.700       Train
 CARDIAC SURGERY        2012-11-30 2849109.782      4152424.500       Train
 OPTHALMIC              2012-08-31   81881.051        75734.000       Train
 OPTHALMIC              2012-09-30  238591.765       202252.000       Train
 OPTHALMIC              2012-10-31  324813.299       345450.000       Train
 OPTHALMIC              2012-11-30  310018.236       277028.000       Train
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with remove second level of `MultiIndex`, change level name and last convert it to new column:

```
df = pd.concat(dict_df).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename_axis('Dept').reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick answer. Really appreciate that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try chaining `concat`, `droplevel` and `rename_axis` as below:

```
pd.concat(dict_df).droplevel(1).rename_axis('Dept')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. :)